# What is the song playing in My Hero Academia Season 5 episode 13 at 19:00?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

As the title say, What song is playing in My Hero Academia episode 13 season 5 at 19:00?

Answer (score 1):

This insert song is called "Sound of the Holidays" by John Underdown.

You can see it credited in the ending credits:

[image: insert song name]